# Passing DataFrame column into WHERE clause in SQL query embedded in R via parametrized queries

Tags: sql, r

I am having a very difficult time passing a column from a DataFrame as well as a Date parameter into a SQL query in R. I have recently stumbled upon the idea of parametrized queries which looks promising for simplifying what I've been doing.

The setup is the following:

```
#Column of values I wish to use in the query in my where clause
values <- df$'column'
vallist<-list(values)


library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)
library(glue)
library(openxlsx)
```

#Function I wish to define with parameters the date and the values from above

```
Data_Function <- function(database,date,vals){



  query <- glue_sql("

                     SELECT column1,
                            column2,
                            dateof
                     FROM database
                     WHERE dateof>=?
                     AND column1 IN ? 
")


df0<-dbSendQuery(database,query)
dbBind(df0,date,vals)
dbFetch(df0)

}
Data_Function(db,c('2021-12-01',EB_List))
```

When I try to run this I get the following error:

```
Error in result_bind(res@ptr, params, batch_rows) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P2'.  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
```

It does not seem to like my "AND column1 IN ?" clause. What is the proper way to pass both of these arguments?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very close to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70572757/3358272), more formalized now in a function. There are a few things to note:

- `dbBind` takes three arguments, but all of the parameters to be bound must be in position 2; position 3 (the ellipses) is any argument(s) for other methods, not the parameters themselves. You can fix this with `dbBind(df0, c(date, as.list(vals)))` or see my next note.
- while it is fine to use `dbSendQuery`, `dbBind`, and `dbFetch`, you can wrap all of that into one call (just like I showed in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70572822/3358272)) using `dbGetQuery(conn, query, params)`. This one call handles sending the query, binding parameters, and clearing the result set automatically.
- if you prefer to still use `dbSendQuery`, then you really should clean up after it: the return value from this call is a "result set" (often using a variable `res`, by convention), which needs to be *cleared*. Most DBI-based systems will auto-clear a previous result when you send another query, but it's better practice to do so explicitly. It needs to be cleared after you fetch data, so a common way to effect this is to

  ```r
  res <- dbSendQuery(database,query)
  on.exit(dbClearResult(res), add = TRUE)
  dbBind(res, c(date, as.list(vals)))
  dbFetch(res)
  ```

  as I've shown in the commented-out code below. The expression in `on.exit` is not evaluated immediately, it is evaluated when `Data_Function` is complete and returning to the caller (though the value from `dbFetch(df0)` is still given to the user. I prefer the use of `on.exit` for other reasons, but if you wanted something a little simpler then this also works:

  ```r
  res <- dbSendQuery(database,query)
  dbBind(res, c(date, as.list(vals)))
  out <- dbFetch(res)
  dbClearResult(res)
  out
  ```

Your function, amended/fixed:

```r
Data_Function <- function(database, date, vals){
  qmarks <- paste(rep("?",  length(vals)), collapse = ",")
  query <- paste(
    "
    SELECT column1,
           column2,
           dateof
    FROM database
    WHERE dateof >= ?
      AND column1 IN (", qmarks, ")")
  # res <- dbSendQuery(database,query)
  # on.exit(dbClearResult(res), add = TRUE)
  # dbBind(res, c(date, as.list(vals)))
  # dbFetch(res)
  dbGetQuery(database, query, params = c(date, as.list(vals)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solves my problem perfectly.